# build `remarkjs` without `highlighterjs`

Tags: javascript, remarkjs

I am already using `highlighterjs` and would rather use the externally included highlighter(js and css) and build a version of `remarkjs` that is much smaller. I can't figure out how to accomplish this. The included `make.js` file is supposed to build the highlighter *only* if the highlighter target is explicitly specified, but seems to automatically include it even if not specified. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/gnab/remark/wiki/Contributing#building for instructions on how to build `remarkjs` without the highlighting library, and still use it with an externally included library for highlighting code.